# Databinding to non-ViewModel properties in MvvMCross

Tags: c#, android, data-binding, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have an MvxListView that binds to a property on the ViewModel which is a `List<MyClass>`.

`MyClass` is a plain old object that has a boolean property named `Completed` that I've bound to the Checked property of a `CheckedTextView` in my list view item template.

When I click on the list view item, it invokes a command which calls a `DoSomething(MyClass item)` method. In the `DoSomething` method, I set the `Completed` property to its new value.  However, because `MyClass` is not a ViewModel with `RaisePropertyChanged` properties, the checked property doesn't get updated in the user interface.

How would I accomplish data binding on this basic POCO to get the user interface to update when the `Completed` property changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I accomplish data binding on this basic POCO to get the user interface to update when the Completed property changes?

Xaml/C# style Data-Binding relies on `INotifyPropertyChanged` - without this the UI has no way to know that it needs to update.

So to get data-binding to work, your `MyClass` objects can't just be a POCO - it needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` somehow - e.g. by inheriting from `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` or by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged directly (e.g. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

---

Aside: MvvmCross does also make other binding patterns possible beyond `INotifyPropertyChanged` - e.g. see `INotifyChanged` in **FieldBinding** in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#rio - but this still requires something more than just POCOs for dynamically updating bindings.